# Svg icon not shown in release apk with R8 enabled

Tags: android, kotlin, svg, android-jetpack-compose, coil

here is my implementation:

```
//coil image
implementation 'io.coil-kt:coil-compose:2.4.0'
implementation 'io.coil-kt:coil-svg:2.4.0'
implementation 'io.coil-kt:coil-gif:2.4.0'
```

```
@composable
fun SvgImage(
svgLink: String,
modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
contentScale: ContentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
color: Color = Color.Black
) {
AsyncImage(
model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current).data(svgLink)
.decoderFactory(SvgDecoder.Factory()).allowHardware(true).crossfade(true)
.networkCachePolicy(CachePolicy.ENABLED).diskCachePolicy(CachePolicy.ENABLED)
.memoryCachePolicy(CachePolicy.ENABLED).diskCacheKey(svgLink).memoryCacheKey(svgLink)
.diskCacheKey(svgLink).memoryCacheKey(svgLink).bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
.build(),
onError = { Log.d("Hello", "Error:" + it.result.throwable.message.toString()) },
onLoading = { Log.d("Hello", "Loading:" + it.painter.toString()) },
onSuccess = { Log.d("Hello", "Success:" + it.result.toString()) },
contentDescription = null,
modifier = modifier,
contentScale = contentScale,
colorFilter = ColorFilter.tint(color)
)
}
```

```
//Implementation
SvgImage(
svgLink = "file:///android_asset/icons/topic_icons/topic_icon_1.svg”,
modifier = Modifier.padding(5.dp),
)
```

> //In android debug view shows:
> Error:Class 'com.android.org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser' does not implement interface 'vi.a' in call to 'void vi.a.setFeature(java.lang.String, boolean)' (declaration of 'k9.k2' appears in /data/app/~~sdONz65JlPgi_46O6Wtsew==/com.abc.teastest-OI_-54phA8WxM0EbpTTwRQ==/base.apk)

//and no svg icon shown

I want my svg icon will be shown even with R8 enabled!

NOTES: My enabled R8 with debug mode and it worked fine, but not for release mode